# php script cron job after 2 weeks send reminder message to specific email address

Tags: php, mysql, database, email

Ok, I have a php script that sends a random code to an e-mail address which the user entered.

I need to make that after 2 weeks the user will get a reminder message to the same e-mail address. This should only happen once.

I have created a database table where I store the user's e-mail and the date they were added.

How can I write a script so that after 2 weeks the user will be reminded by email.

I know I need to use a cron Job, my setup looks like:
[image]

As I understand mailform.php will be used every day at 23 hour, true?
And I need to make that cron Job used script everyday for checking if user passed 2 weeks or no.

My database table looks like:
[image]

Everything is fine, I just don't know how to check if two weeks have passed.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What do you mean by "But I did something wrong with mySql"? What's not working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: What error are you getting .. ?

Comment: I don't get error, but data not saving in my database.

Comment: The reason you can't write it into database may be you specified the 3rd column as DATE type but your code `$query="...'date'..."` is trying to insert a string. Try use `mysql_error()` to get error messages. And this can't send email after a period of time, you may need to make a cron job to do this.

Comment: Is It possible if my database is hosted in web hosting, I'm using windows, not linux? And I used mysql_error(), but still don't get any errors.

Comment: I updated my question about Cron Job, how to make It that daily used script.

Comment: Updated question. I added this $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time()); but the same, not inserting into database. What's wrong with It?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why data is not saved, is because you are actually not saving it.

You need to make a call to :

```
mysql_query($query);
```

to make your record put into the database.

Moreover, in the cron job, the "minute" column should be at "0". So the cron job will run at 23h00 every day.
If you put "*" in the minute column, it will run on every minute of 23h, so 23h00, 23h01, 23h02, 23h03... and so on.

You can find basic help on crontab here : http://crontab.org/

Also as stated before, you should use mysqli_ functions, or PDO modules if you can.

mysql_ functions are deprecated since very long time, and are replaced by mysqli_ functions ("i" is for improved). They work very likely and you won't have to change a lot of your code.

Good luck for you project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following in your script to determine if it has been 2 weeks:
Today = March 14th 2013

```
<?php
$regDate = "2013-02-28";
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+2 weeks", strtotime($regDate)));

if($today == $date)
    //do stuff if 2 weeks
else
    //do stuff if isn't
?>
```

You will have to modify it to your needs but the method of determining the dates is there.

**How it works:**

```
strtotime("+2 weeks", strtotime($regDate))
```

This will take the `$regDate` string and make a time out of it. Then it will add 2 weeks and make a time out of the new time.

```
date("Y-m-d", above);
```

This will then make a `date` which can be used to compare to `$today`

**Please read the manual** : [PHP Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

> > As I understand mailform.php will be used every day at 23 hour, true?

No. You need `0 23 * * * /path/to/script` so it runs at 11pm every day.

This MySQL will get you only the users that who registered two weeks ago (so where regDate was exactly two weeks ago)

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Your_Users_Table_Name`
WHERE `regDate` = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 WEEK), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Then in your cron script you can use that query to get your users then loop through the rows sending out your reminder or code or whatever.

### Crude Example

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM `Your_Users_Table_Name`
    WHERE `regDate` = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 WEEK), '%Y-%m-%d')
";
if (false === ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    trigger_error('there was a query/sql problem', E_USER_ERROR);
}
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // ooo we found users from two weeks ago.
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        // send email to user
        mail($row['email'], 'The email Subject', 'The email message body');
        // update the users table and set remind = 1
        if (false === (mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `Your_Users_Table_Name` SET `remind` = 1 WHERE `email` = '".$row['email']."'"))) {
            trigger_error('there was a query update problem!', E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        // sleep for 2 second so not to hammer mail systems and get flagged as abusive/spammer
        sleep(2);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
else {
    // nothing to do today
}
```